# Display cell address with a =VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'd like to do the following thing:
When my =VLOOKUP formula finds what I need to find, I want to display the address of the cell where my =VLOOKUP formula found what I wanted.

Example:

I want to find "Stack Overflow" in my SHEET2 TAB

[image]

But I'd like to display the address of "Stack Overflow" in the SHEET2... not "Stack overflow"

[image]

What I've tried:

=SI(RECHERCHEV(A39;GW!$B:$B;1;FAUX)=A39;CELLULE("adresse";RECHERCHEV(A39;GW!$B:$B;1;FAUX));"KO")

The CELLULE("adresse";xx) part does not work... :(

Thanks in advance for your help

Jean

Comment: Here is one way (in English) `=ADDRESS(MATCH("stack",B:B,0),2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most `VLOOKUP` formulas can be replaced by a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`. If you do this you can then wrap that formula with a `CELL` function using the `"address"` parameter to return the cell address of the return value.

In this example:

[image]

We are looking for the value in column `B` based on the row in column `A` where value `c` is found. With a `VLOOKUP` you would write

`=VLOOKUP("c",A1:B6,2,0)`

With an `INDEX` and `MATCH` the formula is:

`=INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH("c",A2:A6,0))`

And therefore to get the address of the result you can write:

`=CELL("address",INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH("c",A2:A6,0)))`

To get the result of `$B$4`.

In the example I used `E1` as the reference instead of `c`.

Hope that helps to integrate into your workbook set-up. This is the French Excel translation of the final formula:

`=CELLULE("adresse";INDEX(B2:B6;EQUIV("c";A2:A6;0)))`

Bonne chance!